# Number of visible elements in a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The following problem occurred to me the other day, and I've played around with a bit but can't seem to find a good solution:

Consider a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, 2,\ldots ,n\}$. For every positive integer $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, we say that $i$ is visible if $\pi(i)>\pi(i+1), \pi(i+2),\ldots, \pi(n)$. ($n$ is always visible). What is the expected number of visible elements?

I've tried bijecting the situation to something else, but I can't seem to find one that's actually easier to count. Any ideas?

(This question came from watching some students lining up, and considering which ones could be seen from the front of the line).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your visible elements are also known as *right-to-left maxima*, and their distribution is well-understood. Computing the expectation is especially simple. The probability that $\pi(i)$ is visible is $1/(n-i+1)$ (why?), and so the expected number of visible elements is
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n-i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} = H_n, $$
the $n$th harmonic number, which is equal to $\log n + \gamma + O(1/n)$.

Left-to-right maxima are also known as *records*, and their distribution has been calculated by Rényi: they are given by Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Thanks! I thought they might have been studied before since permutations have been so thoroughly explored, but I didn't know the name/

Answer (score 0):

The number of visible item should be

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} max(0, \pi(i-1)-\pi(i)-1)$$

but I don't know how to average this over the possible combinations.